# Not receiving the message sent by Facebook's Messenger platform by the SendAPI

Tags: javascript, facebook, request, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-send-api

So I have been following the [Quick Start guide on Facebook's Messenger Platform](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/quick-start). And everything runs perfectly. **But**, I am not receiving the message sent from the Messenger's SendAPI. The console log showed the message as sent, but I have **not received the message on the messenger platform**. I haven't changed much of the code given by the guide, except the Token key.

```js
'use strict';

const PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN = process.env.key_one;

// Imports dependencies and set up http server
const request = require('request');

const
  express = require('express'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  app = express().use(bodyParser.json()); // creates express http server

// Sets server port and logs message on success
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 1337, () => console.log('webhook is listening'));



// Creates the endpoint for our webhook 
app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {  
 
  let body = req.body;

  // Checks this is an event from a page subscription
  if (body.object === 'page') {

    // Iterates over each entry - there may be multiple if batched
    body.entry.forEach(function(entry) {

      // Gets the message. entry.messaging is an array, but 
      // will only ever contain one message, so we get index 0
      let webhook_event = entry.messaging[0];
      console.log(webhook_event);

      // Get the sender PSID
      let sender_psid = webhook_event.sender.id;
      console.log('Sender PSID: ' + sender_psid);

      // Check if the event is a message or postback and
      // pass the event to the appropriate handler function
      if (webhook_event.message) {
        handleMessage(sender_psid, webhook_event.message);        
      } else if (webhook_event.postback) {
        handlePostback(sender_psid, webhook_event.postback);
      }
    });

    // Returns a '200 OK' response to all requests
    res.status(200).send('EVENT_RECEIVED');
  } else {
    // Returns a '404 Not Found' if event is not from a page subscription
    res.sendStatus(404);
  }

});



// Adds support for GET requests to our webhook
app.get('/webhook', (req, res) => {

  // Your verify token. Should be a random string.
  let VERIFY_TOKEN = process.env.key_one;
    
  // Parse the query params
  let mode = req.query['hub.mode'];
  let token = req.query['hub.verify_token'];
  let challenge = req.query['hub.challenge'];
    
  // Checks if a token and mode is in the query string of the request
  if (mode && token) {
  
    // Checks the mode and token sent is correct
    if (mode === 'subscribe' && token === VERIFY_TOKEN) {
      
      // Responds with the challenge token from the request
      console.log('WEBHOOK_VERIFIED');
      res.status(200).send(challenge);
    
    } else {
      // Responds with '403 Forbidden' if verify tokens do not match
      res.sendStatus(403);      
    }
  }
});



// Handles messages events
function handleMessage(sender_psid, received_message) {
    let response;

    // Check if the message contains text
    if (received_message.text) {    

        // Create the payload for a basic text message
        response = {
            "text": `You sent the message: "${received_message.text}". Now send me an image!`
        }
    }  
  
    // Sends the response message
    callSendAPI(sender_psid, response);  
}

// Handles messaging_postbacks events
function handlePostback(sender_psid, received_postback) {

}

function callSendAPI(sender_psid, response) {
  // Construct the message body
  let request_body = {
    "recipient": {
      "id": sender_psid
    },
    "message": response
  }

  // Send the HTTP request to the Messenger Platform
  request({
    "uri": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages",
    "qs": { "access_token": process.env.key_one },
    "method": "POST",
    "json": request_body
  }, (err, res, body) => {
    if (!err) {
      console.log('message sent!')
    } else {
      console.error("Unable to send message:" + err);
    }
  }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed it. I was actually **reusing** the webhook verification key and the facebook page's token.
Once I fixed that it was giving the replies. :)

Note: Webhook Token & Page Token are different! One you create yourself **for Facebook to access your Server**. And the other one is generated by Facebook **for your Server to access Facebook's Server**

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

1. Generally `**MY_VERIFY_TOKEN**=Your Custom made Token (e.g:hulululu123)`
   and the '**PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN**=The generated token from Facebook for Developers > Messenger > Settings > Access Tokens > Generate Token'

[image]

2. You have to place the `**MY_VERIFY_TOKEN**=Your Custom made Token (e.g:hulululu123)` in the Facebook for Developers > Messenger > Settings > Webhooks > Edit Callback Url > Verify Token and Verify
3. You have to declarer them in .env and Heroku > Project > Settings > Config Vars or any other server you are using.
4. For more information visit [Facebook for developers Quick Start Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/quick-start/?translation)
   or dm me.